# list the values of a product attribute set in magento

Tags: magento

how do I find the values of a product's attribute set?

For example, there's a product with an Attribute Set called shirts - T, with attributes of Gender, Shirt Size, and Color. Starting with a $_product object, how do I find the values of the attributes, e.g. Mens, Green, Large?

i am able to getting the attribute set value in the following way:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
        $prodAttributeSet = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_set')->load($product->getAttributeSetId())->getAttributeSetName();
```

I want to get all available attribute set values and codes for specific attribute set(i.e shirt - T)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
```

Now suppose you want to access value of manufacturer of this product, then consider following code.

```
$manufacturerValue = $_product->getAttributeText('manufacturer');
```

Comment: i want to show: color,size...all available attribute set values for a product

Comment: $color=$_product->getAttributeText('color');  $color=$_product->getAttributeText('size');

Comment: i dont know what are the available attributes are available for a product i.e suppose color attribute exists for one product not other

Answer (score 0):

As you mention in comment for size and color here i can give you one sample code to use.

If it is a `select or multiselect` attribute, you still need to map the option ID's to option values. That is the case if you are getting a list of integers instead of human readable labels (e.g. for the color or manufacturer attribute).

```
// specify the select or multiselect attribute code
$attributeCode = 'color';

// build and filter the product collection
$products = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
        ->addAttributeToFilter($attributeCode, array('notnull' => true))
        ->addAttributeToFilter($attributeCode, array('neq' => ''))
        ->addAttributeToSelect($attributeCode);

$usedAttributeValues = array_unique($products->getColumnValues($attributeCode));

// ---- this is the different part compared to the previous example ----

// fetch the attribute model
$attributeModel = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')
        ->getAttribute('catalog_product', $attributeCode);

// map the option id's to option labels
$usedAttributeValues = $attributeModel->getSource()->getOptionText(
    implode(',', $usedAttributeValues)
);
```

**Direct DB query example**

Depending on where you want to do this, here is an example of fetching the values without using a product collection. It is slightly more efficient.
    Only use the following code in resource models, as thats where DB related code belongs.
    This is meant as an educational example to show how to work with Magento's EAV tables.

```
// specify the attribute code
$attributeCode = 'color';

// get attribute model by attribute code, e.g. 'color'
$attributeModel = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')
        ->getAttribute('catalog_product', $attributeCode);

// build select to fetch used attribute value id's
$select = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')
        ->getConnection('default_read')->select()
        ->from($attributeModel->getBackend()->getTable(), 'value')
        ->where('attribute_id=?', $attributeModel->getId())
        ->distinct();

// read used values from the db
$usedAttributeValues = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')
        ->getConnection('default_read')
        ->fetchCol($select);

// map used id's to the value labels using the source model
if ($attributeModel->usesSource())
{
    $usedAttributeValues = $attributeModel->getSource()->getOptionText(
        implode(',', $usedAttributeValues)
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want all the attributes of an attribute set you can do the following.

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
$attributes = $eavConfig->getEntityAttributeCodes( Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY, $product );
print_r(attributes);
```